# how to retain excel cells dimensions like (row height and columns width)?

Tags: python, excel, win32com

how to retain excel cells dimensions like (row height and columns width) the data from one excel sheet to another excel sheet (between two different workbooks), i am getting the cell colours, font and layout but the dimensions are getting as default(default row height, column width). So how to copy and paste the data along with the dimensions and formatting.

Answer (score 0):

PasteSpecial with xlPasteColumnWidths.

```
excel.Range("A1:A3").Select()
excel.Selection.Copy()

excel.Range("C5:C7").Select()
excel.Selection.PasteSpecial(Paste=8)
```

Comment: can i know the what excel means?? whether it is a excel COM object or or excel sheet reference from where the data is copying.